# Calculating average price of instrument

Tags: arithmetic

I would like to calculate the average weighted price of an asset based on purchase orders.

I thought it would be `total cost / total amount`.

But looking at the  following sequence:

| operation | units | price | total units | total cost | average price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUY | 1 | 1\$ | 1 | 1\$ | 1\$ |
| BUY | 100 | 2\$ | 101 | 201\$ | ~2\$ |
| SELL | 100 | 1\$ | 1 | 101 \$ | 101\$ |

And the average price is **101$** which makes absolutely no sense... Looks like I am missing something very basic here.

`X.Y:` Eventually I am trying to calculate Unrealized P&L for a trade position.

Comment: The final average? yo buy 101 units for a Total Cost of 201. Then you sell 100 units with an income of 100. Result: you are left with 1 unit and you have spent 201-100=101. Thus, the average cost of the unit left is 101.

Comment: Is exactly what happens in trading stock: if you buy at high prive and sell at low price you have a net loss.